# how can I show Ads in flutter android app?

Tags: android, flutter, ads

Hi I try create flutter android app and I want just like free-to-pay app, my app show some Ads and user pay some money to remove it. and also like app-in-perches and game, Access to the number of features only after payment.
I couldn't find a good resource to teach this. please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Your need is specific to your project, you might not find a resource to teach it directly.

I would suggest in your user details, attach a value to check if user is subscribed or not:

user:{
... user details,
"subscription": false //true if user has subscribed
}

Subscription initial value for every user will be set to false, when user subscribe set it to true.

With this boolean value (or using an enum), you can differentiate app features for different users.

To lean more about about Google Admob with Flutter you can check this codelab:
**Adding AdMob ads to a Flutter app** https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/admob-ads-in-flutter#0

Answer (score 0):

**I got two resources for you to checkout:**

1. [Google admob guide](https://developers.google.com/admob/flutter/quick-start)
2. [pub package](https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads/install)